# In a table of groups and members, how to reduce a certain percentage of members per group?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a table of groups and members.  For example:

```
A Jonathan
A Roger
A Donald
B John
B Lilya
C Richard
C Lorry
```

What I want to do is to reduce the number of members per group by let's say 60%. It doesn't matter which ones of the members are left out.
For example, group B contains 2 members, so I want to remove 1 member (2*0.6=1.2 so it should be rounded downward, I want it to be rounded upward if it was more than .5).

Is it possible to do with Excel formulas?

Comment: I made your example consistent, but it isn't clear if your wording correctly describes what you want.  Do you want the **reduction** to be 60% or do you want to reduce the number to 60% of the original (which would be a 40% reduction)?  Besides the math error in your example, the rounding needs to be applied to the right value.  You describe rounding the amount of reduction, which gives the reverse effect on the remaining value.  If you are talking about reducing **to** 60% of the original, you need to round based on the remaining number rather than the reduction amount.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time action, you can do this with a pivot table. If you need to do it often, this approach may get clumsy.

[image: Final Screenshot]

First, add column headings. I used `Group` and `Name`. select any cell in the list and click "Pivot Table" on the Insert ribbon (far left button).

[image: Step 2]

It *should* automatically guess the range to which you want the pivot table applied. You should just be able to click "OK" to get your pivot table added to a new sheet. Next, add the fields `Group` and then `Name` to the Rows portion of the table by dragging them from the field list into the Rows list. You also need to drag *something* into the Values portion or it won't let you filter for the top percent.

[image: Step 3]

Right-click on one of the names in the pivot table and then click Filter > Top 10...

[image: Step 4]

Setup the filter to whatever you want and click OK.

[image: Step 5]

To make it look more like your original data, right-click on the table, go to Pivot Table Options and then Display tab and check "Classic PivotTable layout". Next, right click on one of the Groups in the Pivot Table and click on Field Settings. Set Subtotals to None and, on the Layout & Print tab, check "Repeat Item Labels".

[image: Step 6]

Comment: The question wording is ambiguous, but this gives a reduction **to** 60% of the original rather than a reduction **of** 60%.

Comment: @fixer1234 You are [technically correct](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CNDkb.jpg). It has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot Table like @EngineerToast has shown is a much simpler way to do this. But I do love a good ridiculously over-engineered solution, so here's one way to do it in VBA. I'm suspicious I did overcomplicate it with the Dictionary, probably could have done it just using some other quick count and then adding the already used letter to an array, but there we are..!

```
Public Sub ReduceMembers()
    Dim GroupColumn: GroupColumn = 1                        'Original column containing your Groups
    Dim MemberColumn: MemberColumn = 2                      'Original column containing your Members
    Dim ReductionAmount: ReductionAmount = 0.6              'Percentage as a decimal fraction
    Range("D1").Select                                      'Start cell for your new columns

    Dim LastRow: LastRow = GetLastRow(GroupColumn)
    Dim Dictionary, DictionaryKey, I
    Set Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For I = 1 To LastRow
        Dim Value: Value = Cells(I, GroupColumn).Value
        If Dictionary.Exists(Value) Then
            Dictionary(Value) = Dictionary(Value) + 1
        Else
            Dictionary.Add Value, 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each DictionaryKey In Dictionary.Keys
        Dim MaxAmount: MaxAmount = Math.Round(Dictionary(DictionaryKey) * ReductionAmount, 0)
        Dim CurrentAmount: CurrentAmount = 0
        For I = 1 To LastRow
            If Cells(I, GroupColumn) = DictionaryKey Then
                If CurrentAmount >= MaxAmount Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                ActiveCell.Value = DictionaryKey
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cells(I, MemberColumn).Value
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

                CurrentAmount = CurrentAmount + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Function GetLastRow(GroupColumn)
    Dim Count
    Count = 0
    Do
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(Count, GroupColumn).Value)
    GetLastRow = Count - 1
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: The question wording is ambiguous, but this gives a reduction **to** 60% of the original rather than a reduction **of** 60%.